# Why cant see/add file "java class" in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

When I am trying to add new file in android studio can't see "java class" file.

[image: Picture]

Comment: make sure you have installed java and created project on java
"there is section where you can choose the language while creating new project"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your directory is set to Android. (See the drop-down option on the very top of the image)

[image]